# Is there a way to open graphs in a new window in VSCode?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, graph, visual-studio-code

I'm graphing some stuff with matplotlib and I need to be able to zoom in on the graph. But VSCode just renders it in its Python Interactive window that I can't do anything with. Is there a way to open graphs in a their own window that allows for scaling and things?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'm a developer on this extension. We don't currently support popping out graphs. If you want to vote up the issue, we have an issue filed for this support here:
https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4976

Until this support is added there is a bit of a work around. You can manually use the %matplotlib ipython magic to update to non-inline rendering. Then when you show plots they will be shown in a popup window. Like so: 
[image]

I can't tell you exactly what command to use as it might vary based on what you have installed in your environment. But %matplotlib auto or %matplotlib qt would be good places to try starting with.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks :) But how do I go back to displaying graphs in Python Interactive now? >.> Should I delete that matplotlib file I made? `"backend: TkAgg" >> ~/.matplotlib/matplotlibrc`

Comment: Sorry I'm not as sure about the matplotlibrc file (I'm not familiar with that file) but for me I was just able to use "%matplotlib inline" to go back to graphing in the window.

Comment: The issue is closed as it is today. How to allow plots to pop out?

Answer (score -2):

Another option would be to set the figure size when creating a plot:

```
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(100, 80))
```

The size is set in inches. So you will effectively recieve a large image which you can then explore in a new tab (look for "expend image" button in the top right corner).